# Extracting pagination number using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the pagination number of a webpage and have tried several methods all to no avail;

What's the right method, and please provide an explanation as to why these following methods do not extract the information as requested:

First method:

```
for i in range(0, 48, 24):
    url = f'https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/find.html?locationIdentifier=STATION%5E1712&maxPrice=500000&radius=0.5&sortType=10&propertyTypes=&mustHave=&dontShow=&index={i}&furnishTypes=&keywords='
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    page = soup.select('span[class="pagination-pageInfo"]')
    print(page)
```

returns:

```
[]
[]
```

I've also tried:

```
1. page = soup.find('span', {'data-bind':'text: total'})
2. page = soup.select("[class~=pagination-pageInfo]")
```

which returns nothing

```
page = soup.select('span', {'data-bind':'text: total'})
```

which returns a bunch of unnecessary things and not the pagination number.

How do I get the pagination number at the bottom?
expected output:

```
1
2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no pagination element in DOM tree you get because this data loads by Javascript. You have 2 options:

1. You can use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and do what you do (search element by `span[class="pagination-pageInfo"]` selector).
2. You still can use `requests` for your purpose, because you can find all page data including pagination in the JSON at the bottom of page HTML. You can easily get it with regular expressions. Full code:

```
import json
import requests
import re

for i in range(0, 48, 24):
    url = f'https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/find.html?locationIdentifier=STATION%5E1712&maxPrice=500000&radius=0.5&sortType=10&propertyTypes=&mustHave=&dontShow=&index={i}&furnishTypes=&keywords='
    r = requests.get(url)
    html = r.text
    full_data_json = json.loads(re.search(r'window\.jsonModel = (.*)</script>', html).group(1))
    print(full_data_json["pagination"]["page"])
```

Comment: I do not understand your regular expression, could you explain a little about whats going on?

Comment: If you open page source code (view-source:https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/find.html?locationIdentifier=STATION%5E1712&maxPrice=500000&radius=0.5&sortType=10&propertyTypes=&mustHave=&dontShow=&index={i}&furnishTypes=&keywords=) and find by text `window.jsonModel`, you will see JSON with all page data.

This regular expression captures all text between `window.jsonModel` and `</script>`. You can read more about regular expressions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) or [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).